# Making a stopwatch using timer for javafx

Tags: java, javafx, timer

I actually have a video streaming application and I want to show the time for how much the two people have chatted with eachother. I have used Timer and TimerTask of java.util class but it gives error as "Not on FX application thread" which means I cant setText to a java fx component using swing thread. This is what I have tried so far:-

```
int timerx=0    //global variable



private void timer(){
/*SHOWING TIME PASSED*/

    int x=0;

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println("working");

            setTime();


        }

    };
            timer.schedule(timerTask, 50, 50);

}
```

And updating the javafx Label as:-

```
    private void setTime(){
    timerx = timerx +1;
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            time.setText(String.valueOf((timerx)));
            System.out.println(time.getText());
        }


    });

}
```

I think the main problem is javafx component not being able to update and be accessed from swing thread. I would be glad to get any kind of help. 
Thank you

Comment: so you stream a video chat? you could go by the system time. save the system time when the chat starts, then you can always calculate how long the chat is going.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but isn't there a simple way just to show the time using thread? I mean the aim is just to show how long the video streaming is going

Comment: Look at [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: @BetaRide I have update the code. Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
long timeStart = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

when the chat start and get how long two guys chatted with something like this:

```
long timePassed = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStart;
```

This will get you how many millisecond have passed. If you want to get second divide it by 1000. Oh and if you want it on thread, just create a thread for this thingy..

Answer (score 1):

ok thank you all for your answers. I solved my problem by running a thread and using algorithm that will show the time in 00:00:00 format which I wanted to make. Here is the code

```
   private void startTime(){
    if(timerStats==false)
    {
    timerStats = true;
    timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            System.out.println("working" + x);

            timersec ++;

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){               

           if (timersec == 60)
           {
               timersec = 0;
               timermin++;
           }
           if (timermin == 60)
            {
                   timermin = 0;
                   timerhr++;
            }

           String seconds = Integer.toString(timersec);
           String minutes = Integer.toString(timermin);
           String hours = Integer.toString(timerhr);

           if (timersec <= 9)
           {
               seconds = "0" + Integer.toString(timersec);
           }
           if (timermin <= 9)
           {
               minutes = "0" + Integer.toString(timermin);
           }
           if (timerhr <= 9)
           {
               hours = "0" + Integer.toString(timerhr);
           }

           time.setText(hours + ":" + minutes +":"+ seconds); 
            System.out.println(time.getText());
        }


    });


        }

    };
            timer.schedule(timerTask, 50, 50); //lastone is time, milli second

    }

}
```

Thank you